# Error: Error allocating IP address. Cause: 400 Error

Tags: fiware

When I try to allocate a new IP for an instance I get this error:

Error allocating IP address. Cause: 400 Error
{"badRequest": {"message": "No more floating ips in pool net8300.", "code": 400}}

Pool full?

Comment: I recommends to see the answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29433680/unable-to-allocate-public-ips-with-fiware-lab