# Unable to allocate Public IPs with FIWARE Lab

Tags: fiware

I am experimenting with fiware labs, I wanted to instantiate an instance of the GIS provider but I cannot since when I try to allocat a public IP I get the following error:

{"badRequest": {"message": "No more floating ips in pool public-ext-net-01.", "code": 400}}

I found some refs on the web but I thought it was wort asking anyway.

Simone.

Answer (score 1):

The problem that you was experimenting is due to the region in which you are working has no more floating IPs (public IPs) available. We have resolve it currently and you should be able to create your virtual machine and assign a public IP. But the new Terms&Conditions of the platform describes that if you are Trial user, your resources will be deleted after 2 weeks. There is a possibility to become Community Users with means that your resources will stay. Just go to [FIWARE Lab Help page](http://help.lab.fiware.org/) and click on the button "Request Community Account upgrade".